# Creating temp tables in sub procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was keen to have some creation of SQL Server temp tables occur in a sub process to break up the stored procedure into parts rather than one big monolithic process.

i.e.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.P422270HRF605CreateTempTables
AS
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpState') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #tmpState

    CREATE TABLE #tmpState 
    (
        StateID VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
        Include VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
    )
GO
```

And I have another procedure call this and then use the temp tables ..

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Membership.GenerateHRF605Data
    @FromDate DateTime,
    @ToDate   DateTime,
    @MemberNo INT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- create all the temp tables required for HRF 605 processing
    EXEC dbo.P422270HRF605CreateTempTables

    INSERT INTO #tmpState
        SELECT StateID, Include = 'N'
        FROM dbo.States
        UNION
        SELECT 'Overseas', 'N'
        UNION
        SELECT 'Unknown', 'N'
```

but this seems to fail at runtime:

```
EXEC [Membership].[GenerateHRF605Data] @FromDate='20190901', @ToDate='20190930', @MemberNo=90001
```

I get this error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Procedure Membership.GenerateHRF605Data, Line 125 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Invalid object name '#tmpState'.

Maybe SQL Server doesn't allow for the creation of temp tables in a called procedure and use of them in calling procedure?

Comment: the temp table only exists within the stored procedure, it is automatically drop when the stored procedure exit. In this case it is `P422270HRF605CreateTempTables`. You have to create it in the main stored procedure for it to work

Comment: You can create temp tables in the main stored procedure and move some of the query to sub stored procedure. temp table created in main stored procedure is accessible by sub stored procedure

Comment: Or you could create a global temp table `##tmpState`, which will be available across multiple sessions. Your stored procs, however, would not be able to run concurrently and you would need to be vigiliant about dropping the global temp table when you're done

Comment: Thank you for your comments, both Squirrel and acutemattiosis, much appreciated ! Food for thought ..  I potentially want to allow for concurrent process running so will avoid the global temp table approach in this instance. I can leave the temp table creation in parent proc and more more of the processing to sub process as per Squirrel second suggestion.

Comment: If you're passing immutable (read-only) data to another stored-procedure you should use a table-valued parameter instead of a temporary-table. If you need to pass mutable (non-immutable) shared tabular data then that's a bad design because **mutable shared state is bad**, mmm'key?

Comment: and btw - if your `Membership.GenerateHRF605Data` procedure is designed to return data back to its caller without mutating any physical (non-temporary) tables, then consider converting it into a Multi-Statement Table-Valued Function (TVFs have **many** advantages over Stored Procedures so they should not be overlooked).

Comment: Thanks Dai ... Yes the stored proc returns 8 tables, which is kind of an unusual design ..  I will look into Table-Valued Functions .. I am thinking TVF are limited to returning just one table, rather than multiple ..   Perhaps I need to re-think my design approach.